# Show sentences word by word. Only one sentence displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

I have a following code:

```js
var P = $('.sentences > p');

P.hide().contents().each(function() {
    var Words;
    if (this.nodeType === 3) {
        Words = '<span> ' + this.data.split(/\s+/).join(' </span><span> ') + ' </span>';
        $(this).replaceWith(Words);
    } else if (this.nodeType === 1) {
        this.innerHTML = '<span> ' + this.innerHTML.split(/\s+/).join(' </span><span> ') + ' </span>';
    }
});

P.find('span').hide().each(function() {
    if( !$.trim(this.innerHTML) ) {
        $(this).remove();
    }
});

P.show().find('span').each(function(I) {
    $(this).delay(200 * I).fadeIn(800);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sentences">
  <p>This is only a simple paragraph #1</p>
  <p>This is only a simple paragraph #2</p>
  <p>This is only a simple paragraph #3</p>
  <p>This is only a simple paragraph #4</p>
  <p>This is only a simple paragraph #5</p>
</div>
```

It displays sentences from div element word by word. Now I want to edit this code and make it displays only one sentence at the moment.

So it will look like this:

1. First Sentence is displayed word by word.
2. 1 second delay.
3. First sentence is hidden.
4. Second sentence is being displayed word by word.

Comment: No one wants to write code for you. Try writing it yourself first. If you have trouble, use your debugger to help you find problems. If you're still stuck after making a genuine effort to do it yourself, then come back and ask for help.

Comment: From you're code, all you are missing is a way to process each `p` with a second delay between them, hiding the previous p's if they are visible

Comment: I tired to write code that will count paragraphs and break on word number, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to iterate on all the `P's` and include a `setTimeout` to show it. Delay you need to calculate for the setTimeout is described below.

Inside this show the current P, hide its siblings and start animating the `spans` it has.

```
var delay = 0;
// Iterate over all the P's
P.each(function(){
  // You need an IIFE to pass correct 'this'
  (function(that){
    // Add a setTimeout to hide/show P's
    setTimeout(function(){
      // Show current P and hide all of its siblings
      $(that).show().siblings().hide();
      // This is what you already had
      $(that).find('span').each(function(I) {
          $(this).delay(200 * I).fadeIn(800);
      });
    }, delay);
  })(this);
  // Delay is past delay + time to fade in all the spans + 1 sec break
  delay = delay+($(this).find('span').length+1)*200+1000;
});
```

```js
var P = $('.sentences > p');

P.hide().contents().each(function() {
    var Words;
    if (this.nodeType === 3) {
        Words = '<span> ' + this.data.split(/\s+/).join(' </span><span> ') + ' </span>';
        $(this).replaceWith(Words);
    } else if (this.nodeType === 1) {
        this.innerHTML = '<span> ' + this.innerHTML.split(/\s+/).join(' </span><span> ') + ' </span>';
    }
});

P.find('span').hide().each(function() {
    if( !$.trim(this.innerHTML) ) {
        $(this).remove();
    }
});

var delay = 0;
// Iterate over all the P's
P.each(function(){
  // You need an IIFE to pass correct 'this'
  (function(that){
    // Add a setTimeout to hide/show P's
    setTimeout(function(){
      // Show current P and hide all of its siblings
      $(that).show().siblings().hide();
      // This is what you already had
      $(that).find('span').each(function(I) {
          $(this).delay(200 * I).fadeIn(800);
      });
    }, delay);
  })(this);
  // Delay is past delay + time to fade in all the spans + 1 sec break
  delay = delay+($(this).find('span').length+1)*200+1000;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sentences">
  <p>This is only a simple paragraph #1</p>
  <p>This is only a simple paragraph #2</p>
  <p>This is only a simple paragraph #3</p>
  <p>This is only a simple paragraph #4</p>
  <p>This is only a simple paragraph #5</p>
</div>
```